# Replace localhost with real domain name in reset password of Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, forgot-password

I am using the **default resetting passwords** in Laravel 5.4. The function works fine, and the email with **reset password link** is successfully sent/received.

However, it still not show the **real domain** but **'localhost'** like something below:

http://**localhost**/password/reset/4c16a78f3c1216de566bc0689694980ac53555311d0214bbb73fbc72870a91f5

Can you tell me how to replace **'localhost'** with **domainname.com**?

And is it OK to do this with `http://` instead of `https://` ?

Comment: Change the `APP_URL` parameter in your .env file :)

Comment: Should it starts with "http://...." or "https://..." ?

Comment: That depends if you have an SSL Certificate or not ^^ If you use HTTPS everywhere on the page, you can link to `https://yourname.whatever`

Comment: Can you use HTTP_HOST from $_SERVER ? I need to change it depending on the server that application is running on?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Change the `APP_URL` parameter in your `.env` file to adapt the app's domain name.

`APP_URL=http://localhost` to `APP_URL=https://yourdomain.com`

If you cache your config (which you shouldn't do in local or test environment but definitely in production), don't forget to use the `php artisan config:clear` command.

Comment: http://... is working but why not working with https://.... ? How can I have https:// with my website?

Comment: Well, that's a completely different topic ^^

Comment: But if you have a VPS/Web server, you can simply use [Let'sEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to get your own Cert

Comment: Sorry for the wrong topic. Anyway, I am using digitalocean droplet. How to do it please?

Comment: They have [an own guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) about that :) @Devith

Comment: Ok. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

update `APP_URL` in .env file and clear the cache to reflect changes

Answer (score 0):

You can update both .env and config>app.php files with the correct domain url